# Implications of keeping Cassandra ResultSet open for a while

Tags: cassandra

I'm using Cassandra Java driver with a fetch size set to 1k. I need to query all records in a table and perform some time consuming action for a every row.
What will happen if I'll keep the ResultSet open (not fully iterated) for a one day?
What I don't care about:

- consistency. If some new record will be written in the meantime, I'm ok to fetch it. However, I'm fine if I won't get it
- fault tolerance. If during that process some node will fail, I'm fine if the query will fail too. However, I would like to detect that from the client perspective.

What I care about:

- Cassandra resource utilization - I don't want to cause cluster outage due to some blocked resources
- lateness - I don't want to block (or slow down much) cluster for other consumers of that table
- I would like to get all records which existed when I started the query (assuming no deletions). However, they don't have to be up to date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paging state is the information about the last read data (literally serialized partition key, clustering, and remaining). When sent to coordinator it will look for everything greater than that. So there are no resources in the server spent for this and no performance impact vs a normal read.

Cassandra does not have any features to allow isolation even within a single query. If data has changed from when the first query was made and the second, you will get the up to date information.